# Expo SDK update causes Playstore app to crash (invalid SDK error)

Tags: android, react-native, expo

I'm using expo for building a react native mobile app and it is ejected.

I recently published the android app to the Playstore on SDK 34. When I updated the app to SDK 35 and published it to the same channel, the SDK 34 version of the app on my android device will try to update and crash. The crash log showed this error: “Expo encountered a fatal error 34.0.0 is not a valid sdk version”

This person who posted on the Expo forum had the same problem I had [(link)](https://forums.expo.io/t/not-a-valid-sdk-version-ejected-app-android-upgrade/18135). My understanding is that it could be due to a mismatch in the release channel endpoint. However, changing the release channel did not solve the crashing problem for the person but clearing data on the app would resolve this issue. This is the same for me, where I had to clear the data on the app in order to do an update without crashing.

Is there a better solution than having the user clear the data before they can update?